# onclick unable to do anything

Tags: c#, asp.net, button, webforms, onclick

C#

```
protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{

//I want to do something here as simple as this below with onClick
label1.Text = "hi";

}
```

ASP.NET

```
<asp:ImageButton id="OBBtn_Save" runat="server" OnClick="btnSubmit_Click" 
  ImageUrl="images/buttons/submit.gif"/>
```

Comment: The above code should work.  What issues are you having? Also, are you debugging in Visual Studio (or another IDE), or running this in a web site and letting IIS do the work?

Comment: *I want to do something here as simple as this below with onClick* - **And???**

Answer (score 0):

check the page directive in the aspx file, verify that the codebehind file is pointing to the right file, and that the class that it inherits is also correct.

Capitalization is important.

another possibility is the wrong dll files is the solution.

Clean the solution then rebuild.

If you want to make sure the event is wired,
all you have to do is += the Event handler in the OnInit method. Then you are sure it was created.

the Downside is if you do this you will also need to -= the event handler in the OnUnload method to prevent memory leaks.

But at least the wire works. and Its in code so you can find all references on it should the time arise.

Comment: when I run it on the site I get nothing from label1.Text, the rest of code functions properly

Comment: When I put it in here it works????                                                    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         label1.Text = "test";

    }

Comment: Try adding the event to the image in the OnInit and Removing it in the OnUnload. The remove is exactly like the Add, Except the += is a -=

Comment: The issue is within protected void btnSubmit_Click{ }--can't seem to make ANY new statements in there to work!

Comment: The only thing I can think is that the signature is not correct. or that AutoPostback is not turned on. But I dont think you should have to turn autopostback on for a button.

Comment: @Jason what does the code look like with the OnInit and OnUnload events? Thx!

Comment: open the code file. Type override and press space. Then find OnInit in the list and select it. You will have an override for the OnInit. Then just type btnSubmit.Click += and you should get an autocomplete. I cant remember the code off the top of my head. But Visual Studio will fill in the blanks. Do the same thing with for OnUnload. And copy the event handler code from OnInit. Then change += to -= and your all set.

Answer (score 0):

You could use simple html controls:

```
<input type="image" onclick="javascript:lbl.value='hi'" />
<input id="lbl" type="text" />
```

Comment: the btnSubmit_Click(){ } lives inside a derived class, here is the code: public partial class PetitionToGraduate : System.Web.UI.Page { }

Comment: @Dennis, what are you actually trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any validators in the page? It could be as simple as your page not posting at all because of a validation error. I know I've done it before in the past.

Comment: I threw out all the validators and expressionvalidators and still not getting anything to work

Comment: the btnSubmit_Click(){ } lives inside a derived class called public partial class PetitionToGraduate : System.Web.UI.Page { }